# Google auth fails using new Google identity sevices method on local http non-localhost domain

Tags: javascript, localhost, google-oauth, google-signin

In migrating from Google sign in to the new Google identity services (ref: https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/guides/migration) opening the Google auth prompt fails locally since my site does not use localhost as the domain. I could not find any specific documentation that might indicate this is a requirement but I have been unable to pinpoint another point of failure.

The local site is running at some-local-domain.org:3000 with the `/etc/hosts` file:

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
127.0.0.1 some-local-domain.org
```

Google OAuth web app configuration is as follow.

Authorized origins:

```
http://some-local-domain.org
http://some-local-domain.org:3000
http://localhost
http://localhost:3000
```

Authorized redirect uris:

```
http://some-local-domain.org/login
http://some-local-domain.org:3000/login
http://localhost/login
http://localhost:3000/login
```

And for completeness the prompt to sign in with Google is being triggered as follows:

```js
widow.google.accounts.id.initialize({
  client_id: clientId,
  callback: onLoginSuccess,
  context: 'signin',
});
...
window.google.accounts.id.prompt(onPromptNotification);
```

The error: `The given origin is not allowed for the given client ID`.

With the above origins I also tested clearing the cache and creating a new credential without success. Tips welcome!

Comment: try using 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost when registering it in developer  console.

Comment: Any luck? I am trying to use 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost too.

Comment: @jalen_blue there is a “workaround”. I’ll post the details as an answer when at my computer later this morning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So Google only supports `localhost` and localhost ip addresses (ex. `127.0.0.1`) on HTTP. As soon as you start using custom domains/subdomains you need to be using HTTPS.

Ref docs (
https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/javascript-implicit-flow#origin-validation):

> JavaScript origins must use the HTTPS scheme, not plain HTTP. Localhost URIs (including localhost IP address URIs) are exempt from this rule.

Attempted to do this via ngrok without success, however `caddy` + `mkcert` worked with some setup. Probably best to check the actual docs but below is an outline of simple setup.

Setup `mkcert`:

```
brew install mkcert
mkcert -install
mkdir -p certs
mkcert -cert-file certs/some-local-domain-cert.pem \
  -key-file certs/some-local-domain-key.pem *.some-local-domain.com
```

Setup `caddy`:

```
brew install caddy
```

Write a config file:

```
some-local-domain.com {
    reverse_proxy localhost:3000
    tls certs/some-local-domain-cert.pem certs/some-local-domain-key.pem
}
```

and update your `/etc/hosts` to include the proxy domain.

Start/stop caddy:

```
sudo caddy start --config ./Caddyfile
sudo caddy stop --config ./Caddyfile
```

Now add your `https://some-local-domain.com` to your authorized origins and visit `https://some-local-domain.com` to try Google sign in.

Note: if using node you might also need to set:

```
export NODE_EXTRA_CA_CERTS="$(mkcert -CAROOT)/rootCA.pem"
```